# Where to download a specific Windows 10 build (iso)

Tags: windows-10, iso-image

I run into problems using **sfc /scannow** - it seems some dll's are corrupted. To replace the corrupted ones, I wanted to download a healthy image for my current build of Windows 10. The problem is, I cannot find my specific build number.

Using the **media creation tool** I was able to download an iso with build number (10.0.)10586 but I need the most recent stable release which would be (by now) 10586.63.

Is there any way to get an image for this build anywhere? Of course I would prefer to download it from Microsoft servers but I just can not find any link whatsoever. Maybe it would also work with a sufficient recent build but I am not quite sure about that.

Comment: Microsoft has not released an individual .ISO for `10586.63` the `10586` is appropriate for your uses.  You can of course just use DISM to replace your local store, which sfc uses, to replace your actual system files.  If you insit on having a 10586.63 .iSO it would have to be generated by you on a system running 10586.63

Comment: thanks, then I'll try it with the latest release. I already tried it with DISM and RestoreHealth but it failed because my Windows update is also not working properly